# Why the scala actor message queue have no bound(size)

Tags: scala, actor

```
 def append(msg: Msg, session: OutputChannel[Any]) {
    changeSize(1) // size always increases by 1
    val el = new MQueueElement(msg, session)

    if (isEmpty) first = el
    else last.next = el

    last = el
  }
```

the append method of the MQueue(message queue of the actor) have no maximum size. Won't this cause outOfMemory?
And look into the changeSize(1)

```
private var _size = 0

  def size = _size
  final def isEmpty = last eq null

  protected def changeSize(diff: Int) {
    _size += diff
  }
```

why no @volatile with private var _size ?
what if append times exceed the Int.maxValue?
do we just expect those will never happend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part of your question: yes, see also this related question [Actors Mailbox Overflow. Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157311/actors-mailbox-overflow-scala)

I think the _size variable is not marked as volatile because it is expected here that the calling method take care of the synchronization. I briefly scanned through the code and various parts of the actor library that call this method are indeed marked as synchronized. 
For the integer overflow: I guess it is indeed expected that this will never happen. 
The actor library that is most used is Akka, which does have support for bounded mailboxes, see [this link](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/scala/dispatchers.html) for semantics and configuration. Apart from that they will replace/be merged with the actors library in the scala distribution: [as discussed recently on the mailing list](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10986).