# How to prevent actor mailbox growing in Scala?

Tags: scala, actor

As for as I know, the `mailboxes` of Scala `actors` have no size limit. So, if an `actor` reads messages from its `mailbox` *slower* than others send messages to that `mailbox`, then it eventually creates a memory leak.

How can we make sure that it not does happen? Should we limit the `mailbox` size anyway ? What are the best practices to prevent the `mailbox` growing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala mailbox size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617580/scala-mailbox-size-limit)

Comment: @larsmans Unfortunately, I do not see an answer I need there.

Comment: @Michael Can you explain why the buffer actor answer is not acceptable for your question.  Based on what you've provided so far it seems like a good solution.

Comment: @Dan I am afraid it is not guaranteed that the buffer actor reading rate is faster than the producers rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having a *push* strategy where producers send directly messages to consumers, you could use a *pull* strategy, where consumers request messages from producers.

To be sure that the reply is almost instantaneous, producers can produce a limited number of data in advance. When they receive a request, first they send one of the pregenerated data, then they generate a new one.

You could also use Akka actors, which provide bounded mailbox.

Comment: these pregenerated requests look exactly like consumers' mailboxes managed manually.

Comment: Not exactly, its a send buffer instead of a receive mailbox. It's on the fast actor side and it's just a way of speeding-up the `pull` response.